# Turning off hover feature in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

Is it possible to turn off the 'hover' feature in CartoDB?

I have toggled off all the fields from the 'hover' menu, which in the visualization wizard shows as being 'off', but when I visit the embedded map on the webpage consuming it, the hover is still on, and 'no data available' shows in the hover window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in CartoDB that was resolved with the most recent release. http://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/issues/122.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, without knowing the URL from your visualization, that you are doing this in the CartoDB Editor (the web interface). Turning off all the fields is the way to do it. I have just tried it in one of my visualizations and its working fine.

Comment: here's one that demonstrates the issue: http://rockymountainhempassociation.org/content/map-test/ in the editor, all fields are turned off, yet the 'no data available' message appears on hover.

Answer (score 0):

It might work to go in to the 'change HTML' mode of the hover window menu and remove the contents from the hover window wrapper div.